# Experiencing issue setting up incoming mail in vtiger

Tags: php, email, vtiger

When I try to setup my incoming mail in the mail manager in vtiger 5.4.0 I am receiving the following error:

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/gvs4us/public_html/ljvt/modules/MailManager/third-party/XML/HTMLSax3.php on line 161

Has anyone else experienced this and do you have a solution?

THanks!

Comment: Your php/apache version?

Answer (score 0):

This library is an old one. You can hide deprecated errors in vtiger config file or simply hide them:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
```